# How to handle events of multiple segmented control in a single view

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have 2 segmented controls in my viewcontroller view. How can I handle the tap events of both of the segmented controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `tag` property on each segmented control to a different integer.  Then in your method you set as the action for when the value changes, check which integer the `tag` property is set to using `[sender tag]`.

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to do so.

1. Add different actions for every segment control
2. Add same actions for every segment control & check which control is tapped using its tag.

   ```
   [yourSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   ```

   ```
   - (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender 
   {
       UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;

       if(segmentedControl.tag == someTag)
       {
           if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
           {
               // your code
           }
           else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
           {
               // your code
           }
       }
       else if(segmentedControl.tag == someTag)
       {
           if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
           {
               // your code
           }
           else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
           {
               // your code
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Apple docs says:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

> You register the target-action methods for a segmented control using the UIControlEventValueChanged constant as shown below.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(action:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

So, you just have to register action for every segmented control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selected mode of segment:

```
UISegmentedControl *tempSegment = sender;
if ([tempSegment selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
    //first Action
}
else if ([tempSegment selectedSegmentIndex] == 1){
    //second Action

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign two different actions to these segmented controls:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(action:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift version:**

```
 @IBAction func yourFunctionName(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){//choice 1

        }else{//choice 2

    }
}
```